# PostgreSQL SELECT latest date only for a combination of different columns

Tags: postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to query data in a way that gets all the instances of `id_description` but only the latest row based on the `date` column.

My latest query attempt is...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, id_part, id_finish, id_metal, id_description, MAX(date) AS date, sort 
FROM parts_finishing 
WHERE id_description='3' 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

...which results in the following returned data...

```
+----+---------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+------+
| id | id_part | id_finish | id_metal | id_description | date       | sort |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+------+
| 37 | 2997    | 1         | 12       | 3              | 2015-01-08 | 1    |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+------+
| 36 | 2990    | 1         | 22       | 3              | 2015-01-07 | 2    |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+------+
| 34 | 2990    | 1         | 22       | 3              | 2013-01-07 | 1    |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+------+
```

I need all the rows `WHERE id_description='3'` though only return one record for the part (a combination of the `id_part`, `id_finish` and `id_metal` columns). The row with `id` 34 I *don't* want returned in this example because it's `date` for the combined part number is older than `id` 36.

On the client side their part number may look like '2990-01-22' so I need *only* the latest record for those three columns combined as a single effective column based on the latest `date`. So I need the query to return the rows of `id` 36 and 37. If it helps the inherent `date` (`date` type) and `id` (`serial` obviously) rows only ever increase, so there is no chance that the `date` rows will ever change from their initial value.

So visually based off of the table above I need the query to return the following...

```
+----+---------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+------+
| id | id_part | id_finish | id_metal | id_description | date       | sort |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+------+
| 37 | 2997    | 1         | 12       | 3              | 2015-01-08 | 1    |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+------+
| 36 | 2990    | 1         | 22       | 3              | 2015-01-07 | 2    |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+----------------+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *seems* to work though I'll need to continue testing with larger amounts of data. If someone thinks they have a more accurate/efficient answer please feel free to post.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_description, sort) 
pf.id, id_description, date, description, inside_hours_k, inside_rate, outside_material, sort 
FROM parts_finishing AS pf 
LEFT JOIN parts_finishing_descriptions AS fd ON (pf.id_description=fd.id) 
WHERE pf.id_part='1013' AND pf.id_finish='6' AND pf.id_metal='30' AND date>'2013-12-31' AND date<'2015-01-01' 
ORDER BY sort ASC;
```

I had to revise the answer though I also realized that the `sort` column is naturally `DISTINCT` so-to-speak since no two records of the same `date` will ever have the same value.